# Entity Framework applying too many migrations

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

We use Entity Framework 6.0 and added a new table using Code First.
As usual, we created the EntityMap and added the entity and the map to the context.
When we try to upgrade the database using the package manager console command "update-database -script", EF wants to apply all migrations (including the ones that are already in the __MigrationHistory table).

Has anyone experienced the same issue and knows how to solve it?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Does adding `-Verbose` to the command illuminate the cause?

Comment: Did you run the prior migrations without -script so they are applied? You could try adding the -SourceMigration and -TargetMigration options. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591621.aspx#script

Comment: thanks @Amy, the -Verbose command lead us to the solution of specifying -StartUpProjectName

Comment: Glad it all worked out!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We found the issue thanks to the comment of @Amy...
When adding the Parameter -Verbose, it became clear that the migrations will be applied to a (new) localDb. We didn't specify the -StartUpProjectName and assumed, it will be the selected default Project. After the -StartUpProjectName was set, everything worked fine :-)

Comment: There are several ways this can happen, e.g. wiping out local code and re-retrieving from source control (startup project gets lost) or switching the startup project to a secondary project to debug it (forgetting to switch back).